# Why does curl_error not work with curl_multi in php8?

Tags: php, curl, php-curl, php-8

I am trying to get response from an array of webpages *parallelly*, with the help of `curl_multi`. Following is what I have tried:

```
$urls = ["wrongUrl1", "http://Wrongurl2.com"]
$mh = curl_multi_init();
foreach ($urls as $key => $url) {
    $chs[$key] = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($chs[$key], CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);  
    curl_setopt($chs[$key], CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);
    curl_multi_add_handle($mh, $chs[$key]);
}

//running the requests
$running = null;
do {
  curl_multi_exec($mh, $running);
  if ($running) {
      // Wait a short time for more activity
      curl_multi_select($mh);
  }
} while ($running);

//getting the responses
foreach(array_keys($chs) as $key){
    $error = curl_error($chs[$key]);
    $header = curl_getinfo($chs[$key], CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    $time = curl_getinfo($chs[$key], CURLINFO_TOTAL_TIME);
    $response = curl_multi_getcontent($chs[$key]);  // get results
    if (!empty($error)) {
      echo "The request $key return a error: $error" . "\n";
    }
    else {
      echo "The request to $urls[$key] : $error returned  in $time seconds as $header" . "<br>";
    }

    curl_multi_remove_handle($mh, $chs[$key]);
}

// close current handler
curl_multi_close($mh);
```

`$error` always remains an empty string, why?.

Secondly I am able to get individual times for all urls. I wonder if the total time taken by `curl_multi_exec` to fetch all urls is same as the largest value `$time`?

Comment: Instead of looking at the string, can you dump the value of `curl_errno`? And from your other question, I think you still might want to inspect the result of `curl_multi_exec`. Also, the phrasing of your question implies that this is broken in PHP 8, but do you actually mean that, or is that just the version you are testing with?

Comment: @ChrisHaas It's just the version I am testing with. Do you mean doing `var_dump(curl_error($chs[$key]))`? It just gives me `string(0) "" `

Comment: No, `curl_errno` which gives the numeric error code. I, guessing it is zero, but I just want to test. Also, is your libcurl up to date, too?

Comment: @ChrisHaas Yes `var_dump(curl_errno($chs[$key]))` gives `int (0)` all the time. Plus the version I get by echoing `curl_version` is  `[version] => 7.76.1`